# Accessing reference wrapper elements in vector c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue, reference-wrapper

In Graph class:

```
typedef std::pair<double, Node&> PIRV;
```

In another class that uses graph:

```
typedef std::priority_queue<Graph::PIRV&, vector<std::reference_wrapper<Graph::PIRV>>, compareEdge> PECMP;
```

Now I am trying to access the first element in the priority queue (`PECMP someQueue`) by doing

```
double a = someQueue.top().first
```

However I get the following error:

```
error: ‘const value_type’ has no member named ‘first’
```

What is the better way to access elements stored in reference wrapper? Thanks

Comment: Put your solution in an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem solved**:

There is a [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) method in the [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) class which allows one to obtain the element store in there

Comment: Just if someone else get there, there is also the `T&` operator that also return the referenced element.