# Using pointers to simplify my code in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Here's my code:

```
    void spin(double angle) {

    // Convert degrees to radians
    angle = get_radians(angle);

    vector<complex<double>> coordinate_list;
    coordinate_list.push_back(co1);
    coordinate_list.push_back(co2);
    coordinate_list.push_back(co3);
    coordinate_list.push_back(co4);

    // Origin point
    complex<double> origin(0,0);

    for (int i = 0; i < coordinate_list.size(); ++i)
    {
        complex<double> current = coordinate_list[i];
        double x = current.real();
        double y = current.imag();

        // Assuming all rectangles origins are at (0,0)
        float temp_x = origin.real() - x;
        float temp_y = origin.imag() - y;

        x = round(temp_x * cos(angle) - temp_y * sin(angle));
        y = round(temp_x * sin(angle) + temp_y * cos(angle));

        complex<double> rotated(x,y);
        coordinate_list[i] = rotated;
    }

    co1 = coordinate_list[0];
    co2 = coordinate_list[1];
    co3 = coordinate_list[2];
    co4 = coordinate_list[3];
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to avoid the part after the loop. I have the co1-4 values already and this method can be called at any point to rotate coordinates. I'd rather access these values directly instead of sticking them in a list, changing them, then assigning them back.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd pack your four variables `co1`..`co4` in a data structure; a `std::vector`, `std::array` (if you use C++11) or a C-style array. Then you can easily iterate over this in your loop and don't need any pointers, references or copies at all.

Comment: You mean pack em in from the start?

Comment: I mean use one variable instead of four. Get rid of four individual variables.

Comment: Also, in modern C++, "using pointers" will not "simplify your code" :) The goal is to *not* use pointers and once you know how, you don't want pointers back.

Comment: @leemes you cannot use C++ without understanding pointers, so this could be just good exercise for OP

Comment: @Slava I'm not sure about that. Clearly, there are *some* situations in which pointers are handy or required (for example when you work with C libraries). But I guess 99% of all problems can be written in C++ without any pointer, requiring no knowledge about pointers, and the result will be very clean *and* efficient. I find templates *way* more important to understand than pointers.

Comment: @leemes when we write c++ programs we have to use libraries except trivial cases. It could be plain C libraries or in C++ but written by Microsoft, so we have to understand how pointers work. I doubt somebody can learn how they work without using them.

Comment: As I said, there *are* cases where you *need* them. But you better look for a decent C++ framework than working with so many C libraries. (To avoid pointers might be a reason.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pointers and refernces:

```
vector<complex<double> *> coordinate_list;
coordinate_list.push_back(&co1);
coordinate_list.push_back(&co2);
coordinate_list.push_back(&co3);
coordinate_list.push_back(&co4);

// Origin point
complex<double> origin(0,0);

for (int i = 0; i < coordinate_list.size(); ++i)
{
    complex<double> &current = *coordinate_list[i];
    ...
    complex<double> rotated(x,y);
    current = rotated;
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t even need the “rotated” temporary, just reassign `current` directly.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I meant! Thank you very much. I'm still trying to wrap my head around pointers.

Comment: @ChrisG As I said, you should not use pointers. Try to avoid them best as you can.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I know, was afraid that too many changes will make it difficult for OP to understand the changes.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a separate function instead of the for loop:

```
void rotate(complex<double> &co)
{
    // rotate it in place
}

// then just do something like this
rotate(co1);
rotate(co2);
rotate(co3);
rotate(co4);
```

Comment: +1 This is what I would have suggested (except that I woudln't pass non-const references but rather have `complex<double> rotate( const complex<double> &co )`

Comment: @FrerichRaabe What speaks against it? Your version requires to make a copy. (OK, complex is tiny but generally speaking). Your version would better be called `rotated` and gerrit's version `rotate`. (In my opinion)

Comment: @leemes: You may find that the compiler doesn't actually create any copy if you do `return complex<double>( x, y );`, maybe the constructor calls get elided. That aside, the downside of having functions take non-const references is that with something like `f(x);` you have no idea whether `f` will modify its argument or not since you can't tell - on the caller side - whether a reference to or a copy of `x` is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your vector<complex<double> > to a vector<reference_wrapper<complex<double> > > and then you won't need the part after the loop. The rest of your code will stay the same.

Comment: I also thought that, but vector doesn't support references.

Comment: Yes a vector cannot store references, however you can get around this by using [std::reference_wrapper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/reference_wrapper/). Here is [example of usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910964/accessing-reference-wrapper-elements-in-vector-c11)